# Peter Land - What or who am I?

Tags: riddle

**What/Who am I?**

> I am the 4th inline of eight, 
> Destructive and Virile some say. 
> Why does no one visit?
>
> PS: I love chocolate and candy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are ...

> ... **Mars**.

I am the 4th inline of eight,

> Mars is the fourth of eight planets in our solar system.

Destructive and Virile some say.

> The planet Mars is named after the Roman god of war of the same name.

Why does no one visit?

> As of now, no man has travelled to Mars, but some have plans to do so.

PS: I love chocolate and candy.

> Mars is also a well-known brand of chocolate bar.

Title: Peter Land - What or who am I?

> Not sure. References to Marsland and Peter Mars?

Comment: Well done :)  Peter Land = Red Planet.

Comment: Oh, it's an anagram. How could I miss that?

Answer (score 4):

You are

> **Mars**

I am 4th in-line of eight

> 4th Planet of eight accepted in solar system (Sorry Pluto!!)

Destructive and Virile some say

> In Roman Mythology, [Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_(mythology)) is the god of war & destruction

Why does no one visit?

> Because currently Mars is inhabitable

PS: I love chocolate and candy

> [Mars Inc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars,_Incorporated) is parent company of many chocolates & you are in (Mars)hmallow

Comment: You're correct :) M Oehm just bet you to the answer though.